# VBA Macro loop fails with Delete method of range class failed but, works for a few times first

Tags: excel, vba

The macro code below is called in a loop. It's purpose is to look at a specific sheet in a workbook and using a defined variable "x" (which is a persons name) delete all rows from a table that is not equal to that name in column "B".

So if there are 700 rows, and David Smith is the current name, the macro should delete any row from bottom to top that does not have David Smith in "B".

The line  that errors out is `Case Is <> Worksheets("Variables").Range("B10").Value: .EntireRow.Delete`

The section that is highlighted is `: .EntireRow.Delete`

The weird thing is that it works for a few times then errors. The sheets that the macro runs on (as in the individual names) are all created from a single workbook.

So example would be that there is a master file, an earlier macro creates a new file using the tabs from the master, then goes through and deletes rows that are not the individuals own data. Does that make sense?

Here is the entire code from the problem macro...

````
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With


    With ActiveSheet

        .Select

        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        Firstrow = 2
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

            With .Cells(Lrow, "B")

                If Not IsError(.Value) Then

Select Case .Value
Case Is <> Worksheets("Variables").Range("B10").Value: .EntireRow.Delete
End Select

                End If

            End With

        Next Lrow

    End With

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub```
````

Comment: This would be way simpler with a filter. Just filter for rows that *don't* contain that value, then delete visible cells. No loop required.

Comment: Highly recommend updating your code to use solution from @BigBen rather spend time updating this. How to filter then delete is well documented on this site & is actually much easier to implement

Comment: What's in those cells when it errors?

Comment: @BigBen the loop is to create the new files from the list of names, then it performs all of the deletions. I will for sure look into the method you suggest. Will that method work in the loop?

Comment: @SJR It can happen with different people. Sometimes after 3 names, sometimes after 6 or 7. It's not consistent.

Comment: @BigBen, Also, I'm not sure how I would delete everything EXCEPT a particular name. If I was trying to delete ONLY that name I would see the advantage.

Comment: You can filter for everything except the name.

Comment: @BigBen ok, I understand the concept of using the auto filter in VBA. Thanks for that guidance.

Comment: @BigBen Sorry, forgot that enter posts and not new line.

My question now is, how would I be able to automagically (misspelling intentional) determine the range and use that range for the filter?

In the current code I use ```Firstrow = 2
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row``` to find the range.

Comment: I tried this but was wrong... lol ```With .Cells(Lrow, "B").AutoFilter, Criteria1:<> Worksheets("Variables").Range("B10")```